# Fastest way to check if atleast one element is in a collection

Tags: python, rust

I once ran into an issue with python where I had to check that atleast one item of a collection interesects with all individual collections in a list of collections.

so for example I have the three collections:

```
A = [
{"a", "b", "c"},
{"c", "d", "e"},
{"a", "l", "k"}
]
```

and a unique collections of characters U:

```
U = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "l", "k"}
```

I now want to find the shortest combination of U where atleast one character is present in all the collections of A.

for example the combination ["a", "c"] would be a solution. ["a", "d"], ["a", "e"] would be too and I want to find them all to find an optimal one later (there are some characteristics associated with each character).

the way I wrote this in python is as follows:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    combs = itertools.combinations(U, i)
    for c in combs:
        if all(set(c) & l for l in A):
            # -> solution found
```

because its possible to have a big list of A and U, the amount of possible combinations can become astronomical so i tried to implement it in rust, however my rust implementation is just as "slow" as the python one.

```
// the input is a bit weird, but this step doesnt take much time i times
let A: Vec<HashSet<String>> = A.into_iter().map(|x| HashSet::from_iter(x)).collect();

let mut possible = vec![];

for n_combs in 1..=4 {
    for i in U.iter().combinations(n_combs) {
        let outp = A.iter().fold(0, |acc, x| {
            for j in i.iter() {
                if x.contains(*j) {
                    return acc + 1;
                }
            }
            acc
        });


        if outp == A.len() {
            //solution

        }
    }
```

i ran both examples just up to the iteration parts and the speed is the same. So the problem is how i check the intersections.
any help on improving this is apprecated, thanks

Comment: For the rust implementation did you use the `--release` flag when compiling?

Comment: yea i used --release.. without that its must slower than the python version

Comment: I think the use of combinations will be killing it here, but I'd need to think a bit more about how to get rid of searching all those sequences

Comment: even if combinations are not the right way to go, i think its still curious that checking in python is so fast compared to rust. i assume what i do is far from optimal

Comment: I suspect you've massively increased the time complexity by doing an extra set of iterations, but my rust is not great

Comment: why `range(1,5)`?

Comment: It always baffels me that people expect a [mostly](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/setobject.c) [C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ace3f9a0ce7b9fe8ae757fdd614f1e7a171f92b0/Objects/genobject.c) [solution](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c) (yes performance critical Python isn't usually written in Python) to be slower than Rust

Comment: This is the problem of finding a minimal hitting set, which is NP-complete. Having a particular input space/distribution or allowing near-optimal solutions might help; what’s your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without a full reproducible example, but I think using `BTreeSet`s, [`is_disjoint`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html#method.is_disjoint) and [`any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any) might be the way to go. E.g. something like:

```
let A: Vec<BTreeSet<String>> = A.into_iter().map(|x| BTreeSet::from_iter(x)).collect();

let mut possible = vec![];

for n_combs in 1..=4 {
    for i in U.iter().combinations(n_combs) {
        let i = BTreeSet::from_iter (i.into_iter());
        if !A.iter().any (|a| a.is_disjoint (&i)) {
           //solution
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the type of i is BTreeSet<&String> in your example, however A is BTreeSet<String> so i added a map(|x| to string() ) to the creation of i. then it kind of works and its faster than before. however now its almost exactly like the python version. 9.5 secs rust and 9.0 for python

Comment: Note that your "Python" version spends most of its time in functions from the standard library that are coded in C or C++, so Rust won't be able to improve much. The remaining difference may be due to the time spend copying strings, so it might be better to change `A` to `Vec<BTreeSet<&String>>` (i.e. replace `into_iter` with `iter` when collecting `A`): [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=92885c83fbccaf58332ce57f0c934d9e)

Answer (score 0):

To find if there are elements in common between lists `a` and `b`:

If your elements are comparable, you can sort the two lists and then scan the lists similar to the [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) iteration.  Except when you reach a point where `a[i]==b[k]` then you have found an intersection and can return `true`.

If it is not possible to impose an ordering on the elements, this tactic will not work.

Comment: I don't follow how this answers the problem at all